# Relationship Between :aot Directive and Warning: *delimiter* not declared dynamic

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am using Leiningen 1.7.1 and Clojure 1.3.0. My question is what, if any, is the relationship between the :aot compiler directive and an error message indicating my defs
are not dynamic?

Here are the details:

If I remove the :aot directive from any of my project.clj files (two libraries and a main that depends on them), I get Warning: *delimiter* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable.

If I modify statements like this

```
(def bene-ssn-idx 16)
(def gic-ssn-idx 2)
```

to include the dynamic directive, I get this run-time error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: clojure-csv.core/*strict*

At one point I remember hearing there was a problem in Clojure 1.3 concerning the first warning message and that it would be fixed.

I'm perfectly happy to live with a longer build due to :aot, but am still wondering
what the warning and error mean, in addition to why removing :aot produces the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a version of clojure-csv that is not Clojure 1.3-compliant: its earmuffed vars are not declared dynamic. I don't know the details on how using ahead-of-time compilation prevents that problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What gave away the clojure-csv version?

Comment: This: "Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: clojure-csv.core/strict". This error can occur only if the mentioned var was not marked dynamic and I reasonably expect that clojure-csv has by now got a 1.3-compliant realease.